# with in a vsts environment git as source code, is it possible clone and push a subfolder from one repository to another?

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-clone

I come across a migration scenario where I have done a bare clone and mirror push and successfully done the migration to new Repository called A , but now I need to clone and push a subfolder from a different repository to A by maintaining the commit history as well. Is there any hack ?

Comment: Have you considered using a submodule?

Comment: i felt it is complicated with submodule